# Python: How to ensure that my text datetime will converted to same format successfully

Tags: python, datetime, date-formatting

I have `log` `text` file and from each text I have `datetime` with this format:

```
2019-04-14 19:42:25.321279
```

And I also have current time:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

This current time will get from several machines and I want to unsure that this format will be the same as my `log` format.

What is the best option to do that ?

I was thinking maybe to read the current time:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

So this time could be with other format so maybe I could convert it to `long` and then to my `log` format?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `strftime()` function of [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object to format the data into string form.

Use

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

to get a string like

```
2019-04-14 16:35:07.750509
```

assuming the last number indicates microseconds.

See http://strftime.org/ for a list of format specifiers available.

Comment: But if i dont know the format in advanced ? maybe i can first convert it to long and then to the format that i need?

Comment: @falukky What do you mean? You know the format of the log file, right?

Comment: Yes but i have this current time that comes from several machines and it could be in other formats

Comment: @falukky If you get current time with `datetime.datetime.now()` in Python, it should be in the same format and shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The format not depend on the format that define on each machine ?

Comment: @falukky No, it depends only on Python.